# Need a wiring diagram for 4 way switch with source in centre and light on end

Tags: electrical, switch

[image]

I currently have two lights in my porch at either end that are both controlled by  separate 3 way switch circuits.  At the middle door it a double box with the supply and two 3-way switches, from each switch is a 14-3 wire to another box on opposite ends of the porch with another 3-way switch.  From those switches is a 14-2 to each individual light.

How would I go about only having 3 switches and turning both lights on at the same time, or in other words i want to tie the two lights together and be able to turn them on/off from any one of 3 switches. I can easily go into the attic and add a wire between the two lights, adding a wire between boxes gets into drywall work.

Similar to the image but the light would have to be off either one of the 3-way switches in the diagram.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the existing boxes?

Comment: I have created an illustration that I believe matches your descriptive text.  Please let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes That is the way it is wired now, the answer below is exactly what i was thinking will work.  I found the original picture I linked and knew it was close, once I slept on it I realized how to do it by wiring the 3-way switch that supplies the light the "normal" way or same way it is now and by using the white wire to supply power to the other 3-way switch first.  Once I woke up I thought i had it figured out but it is always great to have someone else agree and especially to see it in picture form.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Making the connection in the attic saves you

Here's what you can do with existing cables in wall.

[image]

The black-red grouped pairs are **messengers**.  On 3-way switches, "C" marks the common.

### Smart switches

That's the sure way to do this thing, but it's a little complicated.  In this case you re-task red as a signal line (as needed by the smart switches).

Comment: Yes the picture you edited in is the way it is wired now, your answer below is exactly what i was thinking will work.  I found the original picture I linked and knew it was close, once I slept on it I realized how to do it by wiring the 3-way switch that supplies the light the "normal" way or same way it is now and by using the white wire to supply power to the other 3-way switch first.  Once I woke up I thought i had it figured out but it is always great to have someone else agree and especially to see it in picture form.  Thank you very much.

Comment: Is there a program or website you used to create that image or is it a "Paint" type drawing?

Comment: @M.Blyth  Adobe Illustrator CS5 and some clip art I had laying around.  For what I do, CS2 would suffice.